# How to read messages from slack using Java

Tags: java, slack, slack-api

> java.net.ConnectException: invalid_auth

getting this error even after fetching the token for my app

```
SlackSession session = SlackSessionFactory.createWebSocketSlackSession("token");
        session.connect();
        //ChannelHistoryModule channelHistoryModule = ChannelHistoryModuleFactory.createChannelHistoryModule(session);
        SlackChannel slackChannel=session.findChannelByName("notification-hub-test"); 
        session.sendMessage(slackChannel, "Test Message");
        //List<SlackMessagePosted> messages = channelHistoryModule.fetchHistoryOfChannel(slackChannel.getId(),10);
```

Comment: Did you already create the bot in Slack?

Answer (score 0):

If you created a Slack bot channel successfully, you should be able to send messages to Slack as follows:

```
String payload = "{\"text\":\"" + message + "\"}";
Slack slack = Slack.getInstance(); // More on Slack class later
WebhookResponse response = slack.send(WEBHOOK, payload);
```

At this point, you can do whatever you need to do with the response. At the very least, you should get the response code to see if the message was sent OK. To do that, simply call `response.getCode()`.

***WEBHOOK*** is the webhook URL for the channel you created.

To get access to the `Slack` class, you need to import `slack-api-client` into your project. I use Maven to manage my dependencies. Which, for Slack is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.slack.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>slack-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you hfontanez. But I need to read message from a channel. Not the response. I am not sending any message to the channel, only reads them.